# How to use common service for React JS and React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can it is possible to use common code for **react js** and **react web** same like in **N-Tier Architecture** in .Net?

Suppose I have 3 different Project
    1) ReactWeb
    2) ReactNative
    3) ReactServices

Here I have to put references of "**3) ReactServices**" in both "**1) ReactWeb**" and "**2) ReactNative**".

For Example:

Step 1: In "3) ReactServices" Project I have a method;

**LoginServices.js:**

```
export const _signInService = (username, password) => {
    ...
    }
```

Step 2: I want to use this same method in "**1) ReactWeb**" and "**2) ReactNative**".

**LoginWeb.js**

```
 LoginServices._signInService(this.state.username, this.state.password);
```

**ReactNative.js**

```
LoginServices._signInService(this.state.username, this.state.password);
```